# css/sass "disables" my submenu links

Tags: html, css, sass

I tried not to include the code that was unnecessary so you may immediately see the problem. This code works when I comment out the specified code below or if I change the styling (i.e opacity). But I want the style to look like the submenu is coming down from the nav-bar and not just appear and hide below the nav-bar. At first, I thought it was a jekyll problem but after several trial and errors I found out that this was more of a styling problem.

```
<div id="navigation">
<nav class="nav-main row">
    <div class="logo">
    <p>Anatomy &amp;<br>
    Physiology</p></div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="{{site.baseurl}}/index.html" class="nav-item">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-item">SYSTEMS</a>
            <div class="nav-content">
                <div class="nav-sub">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="{{site.baseurl}}systems/index.html">SKELETAL SYSTEM</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">MUSCULAR SYSTEM</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CARDIOVASCULAR SYSTEM</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">DIGESTIVE SYSTEM</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ENDOCRINE SYSTEM</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">NERVOUS SYSTEM</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">RESPIRATORY SYSTEM</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">IMMUNE/LYMPHATIC SYSTEM</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">URINARY SYSTEM</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">FEMALE REPRODUCTIVE SYSTEM</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">MALE REPRODUCTIVE SYSTEM</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">INTEGUMENTARY SYSTEM</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="{{site.baseurl}}/#" class="nav-item">LESSON GUIDE</a>
        <div class="nav-content">
                <div class="nav-sub">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

```
.nav-main {


ul {


    }
}
.nav-item {


    &:hover {

        background-color: $nav-hover-color;
        color: $text-color-hover;
        @include transition(background-color, 0.6s, ease-in-out);

    }

    &:focus{
        background-color: $nav-hover-color;
        color: $text-color-hover;


        ~ .nav-content{
            max-height: 800px;
            @include transition(max-height, 0.7s, ease-in);



        }
    }

}
```

}

```
.nav-content {

padding-right: 10px;
position: relative;
top: 5px;
overflow: hidden; <--(when commented out, link works)
max-height: 0;    <--(when commented out, link works)
background-color: $nav-hover-color;
z-index: 50;
border-radius: 4px;
```

Comment: What is the actual html that's being generated when you run it through Jekyll?

Comment: This is a javascript problem, not a Jekyll one.

Comment: @jtcwang could you re-phrase that where a 3month old developer could understand. Thank you! I appreciate all the replies.

Comment: @DavidJacquel this code totally works outside of jekyll. What would you suggest in terms of a JS solution?

Comment: This is not a Sass problem, only provide the compiled CSS.

Comment: @ken I'm going to assume you use chrome for development (but for other browsers the steps are similar).
Open your page in the browser -> right click on the link that's not working -> "inspect element" -> right click on the highlighted element -> "copy" -> paste it into this question.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It is taken from the code of default jekyll website:

```
<li><a href="{{ "systems/index.html" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">SKELETAL SYSTEM</a></li>
```

Make sure you have set `baseurl: ""` in `_config.yml`, properly.

See [this article about baseurl](https://byparker.com/blog/2014/clearing-up-confusion-around-baseurl/).

Comment: thank you for your reply. unfortunately, it still doesn't take me to the desired page. :(

Comment: @ken you need to give us the html code jekyll generated for you as jtcwang suggested in his comment above

Answer (score 0):

If the base URL is the root of your domain (and if you're sure that this will never change!), you can get this to work without setting `baseurl` in `_config.yml` *(as suggested in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32219661/6884))*.

Just make the link start with `/`:

```
<li><a href="/systems/index.html">SKELETAL SYSTEM</a></li>
```

[The leading slash indicates your domain's root](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/56840/710), so the link in the previous example actually goes to `http://yourdomain.com/systems/index.html`

That's why the first link in your code probably works without setting `baseurl` in the config file:

```
<li class="two columns">
    <a href="{{site.baseurl}}/index.html" class="nav-item">HOME</a>
</li>
```

Comment: thank you  for your reply. sadly, it still didn't take me to the desired address. :(